# Are Javascript connections declared inside functions persistent?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

I'm writing a Node app and initializing a websocket connection.

```
const ws = require('some-websockets-library')
const websocketConnection = new ws(connection);
```

Great! It works.

But what if I declare the connection in a function as below. It seems to work fine. Is there any difference besides the scope of the `websocketConnection` variable? **My concern is that Node won't keep the `websocketConnection` in memory as long if it's initialized in a function with no "global" reference to it. Is there any truth to that?** Trying to learn more about JS.

```
function startWS() {
  const websocketConnection = new ws(connection); // Is this connection less "durable" than the one above?
}
```

Comment: Outside the function you cannot refer to the variable `websocketConnection` declared inside the function.

Comment: Connection would work but you won't be able to reference it

Comment: Ah, yes, I see that it can't be referenced outside the function. So the connection is just as persistent?

Comment: Yes, it still is referenced from the handle is has on the socket. Notice that the variable in your first snippet is not global either, it's scoped to the module, and that doesn't prevent it from being garbage-collected either.